# BigCommerce php api error message "The version of the API specified is invalid."

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am trying to add a customers address in BigCommerce with php API.
My code is:

```
require "bigcommerce.php";

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => 'https://store-y3x98.mybigcommerce.com',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'api_key' => 'my_token'
));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');

Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$address=array( "first_name"=> "Trisha", "last_name"=> "McLaughlin", "company"=> "", "street_1"=> "12345 W Anderson Ln", "street_2"=> "", "city"=> "Austin", "state"=> "Alabama", "zip"=> "78757", "country"=>"United States", "country_iso2"=> "US", "phone"=> "8888888888");

print_r(Bigcommerce::createAddress($address));
```

I receive following error message:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 400 [message] => The version of the API specified is invalid. ) )
```

Please help me.